Is it true that prepositional phrases at the end of sentences create A LOT OF ambiguity?
PPs create lot of ambiguity in sentences especially at the end of sentences. In a structures like VERB+NOUN+PPs there are two interpretations. One is that PPs are adverbial modifying the VERB, another is that PPs are adjectives modifying the NOUN, making it specific or modifying it.
But so many times I find it is very hard to distinguish the differences between them.
Examples:

I received a letter from Mary.
Elon Musk has a lot of fans / a lot of fun in China.
There are some books on the table.
I heard some information from Teddy.

All those of sentences could either be interpreted as adjective or adverbial, and all make sense.

I see adverbials of ownership, location, location in the examples. Location.

Where is the ambiguity in something like "There are some books on the table"? As a native speaker that is totally unambiguous.

You mean "Few people on the Web raise the question". (If few don't, it means that a lot of people do!)

I think the Elon Musk sentence is about fans rather than "funs", which is ungrammatical, but it could be "fun".

It's clearly a typo, but for what? My first thought was funds.


[1] I received a letter [from Mary].
[2] Elon Musk has a lot of fans / a lot of fun [in China].
[3] There are some books [on the table].
[4] I heard some information [from Teddy].

Only the PP "in China" in [2] is an adjunct (adverbial) in clause structure.
The others are all complements:
In [1] "from Mary" is complement of "received".
In [3] "on the table" is a locative complement of "are" in an extended existential construction.
In [4] "From Teddy" is a complement of "heard".

All four examples have their preposition phrases used adverbially, as commented.
We can move the preposition phrases and still get meaningful sentences. If these were adjectival, they would  need to be close to their modificands.

Not sure that I agree entirely with this. What's wrong with letter from Mary? It was Mary's letter that I received.

A prepositional phrase is normally adverbial, and that would be the default assumption for native speakers, so these sentences are quite ordinary. Otherwise it's often indicated by tone/stress, punctuation, etc, as well as word order - if it's important that we know it's not adverbial. But context also helps a lot.

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick and Stuart F.  I’ve simplified my answer.

The sentence "A letter from Mary arrived in the mail" shows that "a letter from Mary" is a perfectly fine NP.

Thanks, @alphabet.  I have edited my answer.

I think it's better to say that "from Mary" is complement of "received"; "on the table" is complement of "are"; "from Teddy" is complement of "heard". "In China" is the exception -- it is a locative adjunct (your adverbial) in clause structure.

Thanks, @BillJ.  Complements are mandatory whereas adjuncts are not.  I’m trying to see the difference between the ‘in China’ example and the rest, in how their meanings change or even how their structures become invalid (in the case of the removal of a complement).

Obligatory elements are always complements: they are needed to complete the verb phrase; optional elements may be either complements or adjuncts.
